# How can I communicate or fetch data in node.js's console from HTML login page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I am creating one server, which is in JavaScript format. And it listens to specific port. When I run it, it loads one HTML page from specific URL. HTML page has Username and Password box and submit button.

When I open that URL with same port from any browser, that page opens successfully only when I click submit button. Than that filled value of Username and Password, I need in my server side.

Here, I attach both server and Login Page code.

Actually, I am new to HTML and JavaScript. But, I tried to make this functionality and didn't get response from HTML button event.

LoginServer.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var port = 9090,              // Port on which to listen
    http = require('http'),   // Call http lib
    url  = require('url'),
    fs   = require('fs'),
    b    = require('bonescript');

// (1) Create server using http lib
var server = http.createServer(servePage);  

// (2) Listen on port
server.listen(port);                        

console.log("@ Listening on : "+port);

// (3) Call below function when request come
function servePage(req, res) 
{

 // (4) Get path for requested file 
 var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
 console.log("@ Request came for path : "+path);

  // (5) Read the requested file content from file system
 fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function (err, data) 
 {

  // If found any ERROR then call given function
  if (err) 
  {                                      
   return send404(res); 
  }

  // Write down html code at end.
  else
  {  
   res.write(data, 'utf8');                        
   res.end();
  } 
 });

}

function send404(res) 
{
 res.writeHead(404);
 res.write('404 - page not found');
 res.end();
}
```

Login.html

```
<html>

<!-- Set TAB Title -->
<head> <title> RxLogin </title> </head>

<body>

<form name="Login" action="http://192.168.7.2:9090" method="get">

<table>

<tr> <th> Username </th> <th> <input type="text" name="usrnm" ID="textbox_1"/> </th> </tr>
<tr> <th> Password </th> <th> <input type="password" name="passwd"/> </th> </tr>
<tr> <th> <input type="button" value="Login"/> </th>  </tr>

</table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I need the solution to get data from that HTML login page's credential data in server side, when submit button press.

So, finally I want code in "LoginServer.js" file. And I also want submit button click event code in "Login.html" file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the form to your server i suggest you to take a look to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

Hope it helps